# How to activate a Conda Environment from the "sh" shell (on Nodejs)?

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, ubuntu, conda

I can activate the Conda Environment with any problems from the `bash` shell. I can use this two options on `bash`:

```
source activate env_name
. activate env_name
```

But I am using the method `exec` of Node to run the activation of the environment. Node uses `sh` shell in order to run commands. I tried the commands above, but they did not work. I got this error

```
/bin/sh: 1: /env_name/bin/source: not found
```

So I had to use this command to run the environment

```
const child_process = require('child_process')
child_process.exec('bash -c "source activate env_name"')
```

Is there a better way to do this to make it work on Ubuntu?

I run this on Windows and it is enough to make it work

```
child_process.exec('activate env_name')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conda doesn't do well right now (in conda 4.3.x) with shells that aren't "advanced" like bash and zsh.  Pure posix dash and the busybox shells, for example, don't work right now.

Good new though... They soon will.  Support for a larger variety of shells is a feature of conda 4.4.  The base PR for this work was https://github.com/conda/conda/pull/5044, and there are several follow-ons.

Conda 4.4.0 should be released into [canary](https://www.continuum.io/blog/developer-blog/what-conda-canary) in the next several weeks.